# SQL Server partitioniong

Tags: sql-server, database-partitioning

I am working on a heavy record set database in MS SQL 2016. So I want to use row table partition feature to improve speed.

As we know partition feature is working on partition column of a table. Let's say [Date Column] of  a table. In our scenario, have many tables that need to partition because of heaver record set in 5 to 7 tables. Each table not have that [Date column]. Also not possible to add that column in each table.

So is there any way I can select partition column of another table or something else.

Comment: Partition is based on a column, if you don't have such column you can't partition. Do you really need partition? How heavy is your "heavy", and improve speed of selects or updates/inserts?

Comment: The partitioning column must exist the table being partitioned. Partitioning will not automagically improve speed. Index and query tuning are the ways to improve performance. Partitioning may improve performance of what would otherwise be full scans, but only if partition elimination occurs.

Comment: Provide us with some sample data to assist.

Comment: Actually, partitioning can reduce speed in some cases.

Comment: We have record set around each database with 50 to 60 millions records. Once become table large it causing performance issue for all the quires.

Answer (score 0):

The best option is to add a common column to all tables that you will then use to partition by.
You must already have a way of relating the different tables to each other so you can use this to tag each table with the correct Partition column.

This column could be as simple as an int with YYYYMM as values for monthly partitions.

You also need to make sure your queries are "Partition Aware".
This means that you should include this column in your WHERE Clause and also your JOIN Clauses for any queries.
Use Query Plans to make sure you are getting Partition Elimination on your queries.

If you can't change the model (but can add partitions???) then you could implement the partitioning  with different columns in each table provided you have a single column in each table that you can partition on named ranges - but if you have 1-many relationships then it is unlikely that the child tables keys will be consecutive relative to the parent table. Note that this approach will make your "partition aware" queries more complex to craft.

Comment: We have 1-many relationships as you said but if we go with datetime column. How we can achieve partition on child table respective to parent table. Whenever parent table value move in any partition all child table need to move in that partition.